# How to handle many form calculations appropriately in MVC5?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a project to emulate a paper form that has hundreds of fields of input.  There is a main calculation section that has rows that add or subtract from the total.  Some fields even have convoluted formulas in relation to other rows. I intend for the calculations to happen immediately with the use of JQuery and then redo the calculations on the back end to verify the data.  I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC5 and C#.

This is a very broad question, but how would one go about solving this problem? Is there a specific design pattern I should use that would make life easier? Is there a class like WebGrid that you would recommend?

The end users are not technical, so I'm trying to keep it as paper-like as possible, which means no Turbotax-like interface.  There will be requests to change rows periodically so I hope to make all those changes in one place, as opposed to changing it in the front end and back end separately.

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to do almost all the things in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Put all calculation on client. You can use [KnockOutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) or another JS library, which support bindable, computed fields. In knockOut you can declare computed fields, which will be automatically recalculated after the change desired field